# What does (someone is just F-ing with somebody else) mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I'm sorry if it's inappropriate, that phrase I heard while I was watching *American Horror Stories*, but I don't think it has something to do with having s3x. In order to avoid something vulgar around here, I've changed the conversation a bit so that it won't sound inappropriate.

Anyway here's the conversation:

> X: Do you really love me or are you just experimenting with love or are you just **fucking with me**?
>
> Y:  (Y grabs X's hands) No. I'm not fucking with you. But, I'm not sure with the other two.

I did try to search that phrase. However, sadly. Google let me down and gave me the inappropriate results. If I'm guessing it correctly, does it exactly mean like the phrasal verb **mess with somebody**?

Comment: *mess with somebody* is a very good way to understand it.

Comment: Searching for 'slang meaning "fucking with"' I get https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fuck+with : *rude slang* To tease or attempt to deceive someone, typically as part of a prank or practical joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  It means to mess with someone; to tease or play a prank on someone.

So here it means "... or are you just pretending to love me?"